# SOLR- search and bring results based on partial search

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solr-search

I have a product old code and new code.The old product code would be like 000000000000988340 and am using hybris + solr search.

I have setup the attribute "oldproductcode" for solr indexing and when i do search 000000000000988340 in the search box ,am  getting the  results.
But what I want is to search  only with 988340 instead of using the leading zeros and I want the results to be shown ,how can i do that in Solr settings.

I do see all these options and i did tried the wildcard ,and it doesn't seem to work ,please advise using the following option how can i make this work

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with hybrid/sap commerce cloud, but on the Solr side you could do this by adding a second field as a text field with a keywordtokenizer and having a pattern replacement filter that removes any zeroes at the beginning of the string. You'd then search against both fields with your input string (.. in reality, you'd only need this field, as you want both the queries and the indexed content to be normalized in the same way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply enabled the option below with PREFIX and it started working .
Thanks all for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This approach may work (using EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory) :

In your `schema.xml` file associated with your Solr server, add this new fieldType :

```
<fieldType name="text_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

then apply this custom analyzer to your "oldproductcode" field :

```
<field name="oldproductcode" type="text_edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Ben, appreciate your quick response, however i was able to achieve this in the settings given in my answer, thanks again for your efforts and time .Much appreciated !